# Derive taproot addresses from BIP39 mnemonic

Tags: mnemonic-seed, taproot

I have two questions, but here's some general info to start: I wrote a little C program to generate addresses for BIP44, BIP49, and BIP84, and I wanted to (finally) update it to include BIP86. I've been trying to follow the instructions [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/116391), but for some reason it *mostly* isn't working.  I'm using Visual Studio with libsecp256k1 from nuget (secp256k1_vc143). Unless otherwise stated, I am using the test vector mnemonic `"abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon about"`.

First question: In the link, there is the "non-recommended" way to get the p2tr address, but there are no test vectors for that.  I would just like to confirm that for the test vector mnemonic above the result for `m/86'/0'/0'/0 index 0` should be `bc1pej9yh3jd39aam30mctm8paaghg9nsemezpk0zg3udlza0nt0cy2sqvps98`?

Second question: I'm trying to use libsecp256k1's `secp256k1_ec_pubkey_tweak_add()` function to perform the tweaking, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Here is example code, where the initial private key you see is the final one when deriving the test vector mnemonic.  I also hardcoded the `SHA256("TapTweak")||SHA256("TapTweak")` bit in `tweak96`.

```
char* seckey = "41f41d69260df4cf277826a9b65a3717e4eeddbeedf637f212ca096576479361";
uint8_t* privkey = calloc(32, 1);
HexToBin(seckey, privkey, 32);

secp256k1_context* ctx = secp256k1_context_create(SECP256K1_CONTEXT_SIGN);
secp256k1_pubkey* pubkey = malloc(sizeof(*pubkey));
size_t clen = 33;

secp256k1_ec_pubkey_create(ctx, pubkey, privkey);

uint8_t* Pb = calloc(33, 1);
secp256k1_ec_pubkey_serialize(ctx, Pb, &clen, pubkey, SECP256K1_EC_COMPRESSED);

char* tweak96 = "e80fe1639c9ca050e3af1b39c143c63e429cbceb15d940fbb5c5a1f4af57c5e9e80fe1639c9ca050e3af1b39c143c63e429cbceb15d940fbb5c5a1f4af57c5e90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
uint8_t* tweak96B = calloc(96, 1);
HexToBin(tweak96, tweak96B, 96);
memcpy(tweak96B + 64, Pb + 1, 32);

uint8_t* t = calloc(32, 1);
SHA256(tweak96B, 96, t);

secp256k1_ec_pubkey_tweak_add(ctx, pubkey, t);

uint8_t* Qb = calloc(33, 1);
char* addr = calloc(65, 1);

secp256k1_ec_pubkey_serialize(ctx, Qb, &clen, pubkey, SECP256K1_EC_COMPRESSED);

segwit_addr_encode(addr, "bc", 1, Qb + 1, 32);
```

According to the test vectors and [this site](https://bitcoiner.guide/seed/), I should get `bc1p5cyxnuxmeuwuvkwfem96lqzszd02n6xdcjrs20cac6yqjjwudpxqkedrcr`, but I get `bc1pvhzh08gqauq66acu3s8a2zwyxlhexsmwqj2gey9965du0u6snwms5x4qv0`.  For most mnemonics I've tried, I get the wrong result, except for `"warrior pudding spend capital category hospital village wait planet organ coach churn"`, where I get the correct answer of `bc1psug2nkgfkemndxq9mwqsdxg4rvdd9s8ztysft0lpxsy0f5jmufksz0tjup` and I don't know why. My code works fine for BIP44, BIP49 and BIP84, but not the tweaked BIP86. Can anyone tell me what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that finds this question later, here's the solution:

The instructions [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/116391/84856) missed an important step: the `lift_x()` function as described in [BIP 340](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki). After implementing `lift_x()` and an ec point addition function using the mpir library, I realized I was using a really old version of libsecp256k1, so I didn't have the functions `secp256k1_xonly_pubkey_from_pubkey()` and `secp256k1_xonly_pubkey_tweak_add()`. The second one does steps 4 and 5 below.  Updating libsecp256k1 at the beginning would have saved me a lot of time, so that's a facepalm. Learned a bit about ec math, so it wasn't a complete waste.  Anyway, now it works.

To clarify, here is a slightly more detailed version of the steps to convert a private key to a taproot address (with taptweak):

1. Compute the public key *P = privkey * G.*
2. Let *Pb* be the serialization of *P* in x-only form.
3. Compute the tweak *t = SHA256(SHA256("TapTweak") || SHA256("TapTweak") || Pb)*, interpreted as 32-byte big endian encoded integer.
4. Create a new ec point *Plift* where the x-coordinate is *Pb*, and the y-coordinate is the result of the `lift_x()` function
5. Compute the tweaked public key *Q = Plift + (t * G).*
6. Let *Qb* be the serialization of *Q* in x-only form.
7. The address is *bech32m_encode(payload=Qb, version=1)*.